# Modal gallery with MySQL

Tags: php, arrays

so I am making image modal gallery and I have this issue which a can't resolve. I want to fetch first image from database table.  The issue is that I'm getting error Call to a member function on array error.

My function is this:

```
public function fetch_first_photo($id){
  global $pdo;
  $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM photo WHERE id_galeria = ? LIMIT 1');
  $query->execute([$id]);
  return $query->fetch();
  }
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<?php 
$first_photo = new Photo;

foreach ($gallery as $gallery):
  $first_photo = $first_photo->fetch_first_photo($gallery['id_galeria']); ?>
  <div class="col"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pin-map" style="display: inline;padding-bottom: 1px;margin-bottom: 10px;"></svg>
    <h3 class="text-center" style="width: 80%;display: inline;margin-left: 10px;"><?php echo $gallery['nazov'] ?></h3><a data-bs-target="#modal-1<?php echo $i ?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#">
    <img class="img-fluid gallery" data-bss-hover-animate="pulse" src="assets/img/Referencie/<?php echo $gallery['nazov'];?>/<?php echo $first_photo['url'];?>">
   </a>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
> fetch_first_photo() on array in
> /data/8/b/8b8f5c3a-29b5-4e71-a68b-85bf5fa61ab2/falconi.eu/web/referencie2.php:30
> Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
> in/data/8/b/8b8f5c3a-29b5-4e71-a68b-85bf5fa61ab2/falconi.eu/web/referencie2.php
> on line 30

Thank you very much for all your responses.

Comment: `foreach ($gallery as $gallery)` I'd use different names here, something like `foreach ($galleries as $gallery)`

Comment: Did you `var_dump($gallery)` inside your loop to see what it contains?

Comment: `var_dump($gallery)` prints first name of gallery and after that all I see is Fatal Error

Comment: If you are getting errors, you need to show us the _full, exact_ error message without any abbreviations or paraphrasing. Otherwise, we are always going to be a bit uncertain what the real problem is.

Comment: Thanks. That error means `$first_photo` is an array. Therefore it's not an object you can call a function on. Was there something in that message which is unclear to you? Do you know what an array is? Anyway we cannot help you debug it really, because you didn't show us where you defined the `$first_photo` variable to begin with. I'd also strongly recommend _not_ immediately overwriting it with the result of calling that function. Using the same variable name for multiple different purposes in the same script is a great recipe for confusion and bugs. It's also completely unnecessary.

Comment: In fact, the `$first_photo = $first_photo->...` silliness could easily be the cause of your problem. Maybe `$first_photo` is defined ok to begin with, but the next time your loop runs, you've overwritten it with the result of the fetch_first_photo() function which as we can see from your code returns (...you guessed it...) an array. So please do some simple debugging and check whether this error occurs the first time it loops, or the second.

Comment: My `$first_photo` is defined as `$first_photo = new Photo;` and thank you so much for your time and I think everything else is clear to me. And my error occurs the second time in loop, first time works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-using variable names for to represent different things in the same script is never a good idea - it makes your code harder to understand, which means it's easy to get confused when writing it and testing it, and it's very likely to cause subtle bugs.

It looks like it's the cause of your problem here too. This code:

```
<?php 
$first_photo = new Photo;

foreach ($gallery as $gallery):
  $first_photo = $first_photo->fetch_first_photo($gallery['id_galeria']); ?>
  <div class="col"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pin-map" style="display: inline;padding-bottom: 1px;margin-bottom: 10px;"></svg>
    <h3 class="text-center" style="width: 80%;display: inline;margin-left: 10px;"><?php echo $gallery['nazov'] ?></h3><a data-bs-target="#modal-1<?php echo $i ?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#">
    <img class="img-fluid gallery" data-bss-hover-animate="pulse" src="assets/img/Referencie/<?php echo $gallery['nazov'];?>/<?php echo $first_photo['url'];?>">
   </a>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

should be changed to:

```
<?php 
$first_photo = new Photo;

foreach ($gallery as $galleryItem):
  $first_photo_data = $first_photo->fetch_first_photo($gallery['id_galeria']); ?>
  <div class="col"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pin-map" style="display: inline;padding-bottom: 1px;margin-bottom: 10px;"></svg>
    <h3 class="text-center" style="width: 80%;display: inline;margin-left: 10px;"><?php echo $galleryItem['nazov'] ?></h3><a data-bs-target="#modal-1<?php echo $i ?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#">
    <img class="img-fluid gallery" data-bss-hover-animate="pulse" src="assets/img/Referencie/<?php echo $galleryItem['nazov'];?>/<?php echo $first_photo_data['url'];?>">
   </a>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have renamed the variable which holds the return value of the `fetch_first_photo` function to `$first_photo_data`, so it is not overwriting the value of `$first_photo`.

Why? Well, in your original code it appears that `$first_photo` is defined ok to begin with, but the next time your loop runs, you've overwritten it with the result of the `fetch_first_photo()` function. As we can see from your code that function returns an array, so you cannot then call a function on it, and this would lead to the error you quoted.

N.B. Although not directly the cause of the issue, I also renamed the item variable in the `foreach`, for the same reason: having good, clear, unambiguous code.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working now. You are a legend <3.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully this principle of not re-using your variable names is useful information which you can apply to all your programs.